# In Python, How to put constraits on four random numbers making two negative and two positive and equating to 0?

Tags: python, numpy, random, constraints, weighted-average

How do i make two random negative numbers and two positive random numbers equal zero.For example,

```
array([-.7,-.2,.8,.10]) = 0. [-.3,.2,-.5,.6] = 0.
```

The numbers are constrained between -1 and 1. Size is 4 with 2 neg,2 pos.
 I dont want np.uniform answers I need 4 random nums in arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3] = 0

```py
equate_to_zero = np.random.rand(4)

equate_to_zero = np.random.randint(-1,1,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import random
numbers = [random.random(), random.random()]
third = 1
while third < -1 or sum(numbers) + third > 1:
  third = -random.random() * sum(numbers)
numbers.append(third)
numbers.append(-sum(numbers))

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your restrictions do not really make this a random choice:

Repeat:

- pick two random numbers between `0` and `1` ( you get 2 positive numbers)
- pick a number between 0 and sum of your both positives, negate it
- the last number is either 0 or the negative of the sum of all your picked numbers to fullfill your *zero sum* constraint.
- check if all numbers are in range of `-1 <= value <= 1` to fullfill your second constraint:

---

```
import random

nums = [] 
while not (nums and sum(nums) == 0 and all( -1 <= v <= 1 for v in nums)):
    nums.clear()
    nums.append(random.uniform(0,1))     
    nums.append(random.uniform(0,1))     
    nums.append(-random.uniform(0, min(1,sum(nums)))) 
    nums.append(-sum(nums))

print(nums, sum(nums), '\n', all(-1<=v<=1 for v in nums))
```

Some outputs:

```
[0.13384619226474825, 0.16430615981325492, -0.129440537948814, -0.16871181412918917]
0.0 True
[0.5272349957681723, 0.9907612252755699, -0.6154545496761035, -0.9025416713676386]
0.0 True
[0.08800418781896269, 0.019709746108289794, -0.09774957976019887, -0.009964354167053616]
0.0 True
[0.2601694747029456, 0.19440408898981965, -0.44030666093322246, -0.014266902759542788]
0.0 True
[0.1335966043546949, 0.009585672653110833, -0.05410243127485397, -0.08907984573295175]
0.0 True
[0.1540847175501423, 0.45879371832292193, -0.5358914298443959, -0.07698700602866837]
0.0 True
[0.4888630325349226, 0.41638764362913905, -0.5841420728403781, -0.3211086033236835]
0.0 True
```

You can simplify and speed up the condition checking to:

```
nums = [] 
while True:
    nums.clear()
    nums.append(random.uniform(0,1))  # at max 1
    nums.append(random.uniform(0,1))  # at max 1
    nums.append(-random.uniform(0, min(1,sum(nums)))) # at max 1, negated
    if sum(nums) <= 1:                # ensure at max 1
        nums.append(-sum(nums))       # negated at max 1 breaks the loop
        break
```

but the constraints are less visible that way. Math ensures you get 2 positives, 2 negatives and zero sum

Answer (score 0):

pick 1 random negative

```
from random import uniform
neg1 = uniform(-1,0)
```

pick one random positive

```
pos1 = uniform(0,1)
```

your second negative must meet the condition of n1 + n2 < p1 - 1.0

```
neg2 = uniform(min(pos1+1-abs(neg1),1)*-1,0)
```

second positive MUST be the difference

```
pos2 = abs(neg1) + abs(neg2) - pos1
numbers = [neg1,neg2,pos1,pos2]
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the second positive will be between 0 and 1.

Comment: `pos1 = random.uniform(max(0, sum_of_negatives - 1), min(1, sum_of_negatives))` seems like a good bet.

Comment: lol yeah i think theres no way to ensure `n1+n2 < p1-1` unless you pick `n2` after `p1` see final answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random` module!

```
import random
x=random.uniform(-1,1)

y=random.uniform(-1,1)

output = [x,-x,y,-y]

print(output,sum(output))
```

Output of this program is:

```
[-0.9694091718268465, 0.9694091718268465, -0.6982058977316767, 0.6982058977316767] 0.0
```

Comment: Interesting. They won't be random but the examples in the OP posted are not random either.

Comment: Nothing in this world is random my friend!

Comment: @Solen'ya good answer but as stated I need random numbers not uniform. Even though I showed uniform in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no solution without fiddling here or there, that'd be my approach: Pick two random negative numbers, pick two random positive numbers, and subtract the mean of the four values. Both negative numbers will stay negative, both positive numbers will stay positive. The only possible unwanted behavior I can think of, is that one of the negative values becomes `< -1` resp. one of the positive values becomes `> 1` after subtracting the mean. In that case, just pick four new values.

```py
import numpy as np

while True:
    numbers = np.hstack((np.random.rand(2), -np.random.rand(2)))
    numbers -= np.mean(numbers)
    print(numbers)
    print(np.sum(numbers))
    if np.all(np.abs(numbers) <= 1):
        break
```

Output for the described case with unwanted behavior:

```
[ 0.75018366  0.82691508 -0.55406187 -1.02303687]
2.220446049250313e-16
[ 0.57616847  0.6875385  -0.29527166 -0.9684353 ]
-2.220446049250313e-16
```

Gladly, this case doesn't occur that often, especially for more than two consecutive occurrences.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using a rejection method (i.e. without generating candidates and rejecting those that do not meet the constraints).  Here's a function, `generate_samples`, that generates `n` samples directly:

```
import numpy as np


def generate_samples(n):
    samples = np.empty((n, 4))

    # Positive random values placed in the first two columns of `samples`.
    samples[:, :2] = np.random.rand(n, 2)

    # s holds the sum of each of the positive pairs.
    s = samples[:, :2].sum(axis=1)

    # The next several lines generate negative pairs whose sums are -s.
    # These pairs are stored in the last two columns of `samples`.
    sum_exceeds_one = s > 1
    # If, for a given positive pair, their sum S is greater than 1, we
    # choose the first negative value from the interval [-1, 1-S]. If the
    # sum is not greater than 1, we choose the negative value from [-S, 0].
    lo = np.where(sum_exceeds_one, -1, -s)
    hi = np.where(sum_exceeds_one, 1 - s, 0)
    samples[:, 2] = np.random.uniform(lo, hi)
    # The other negative value is -S minus the first negative value.
    # Then the sum of the two negative values is -S, and therefore the
    # sum of all four values is 0.
    samples[:, 3] = -s - samples[:, 2]

    return samples
```

For example,

```
In [4]: x = generate_samples(10)                                                

In [5]: x                                                                       
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.9073454 ,  0.71388572, -0.98977258, -0.63145855],
       [ 0.10764888,  0.45412392, -0.21106885, -0.35070395],
       [ 0.94022813,  0.67878085, -0.93902162, -0.67998736],
       [ 0.12237378,  0.6191983 , -0.10095831, -0.64061377],
       [ 0.75622602,  0.68512258, -0.78848084, -0.65286777],
       [ 0.0413813 ,  0.38584856, -0.35001458, -0.07721527],
       [ 0.7999729 ,  0.29194787, -0.17552097, -0.91639981],
       [ 0.90668063,  0.73613531, -0.96464118, -0.67817477],
       [ 0.73393297,  0.55074045, -0.90966483, -0.37500858],
       [ 0.60739055,  0.94326166, -0.70910385, -0.84154836]])

In [6]: x.sum(axis=1)                                                           
Out[6]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

The marginal distribution of positive pairs will be uniform in the positive unit square, and the negative pairs will be uniform in the negative unit square.  Here's a code snippet that uses matplotlib that illustrates the distributions of the points:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2000
data = generate_samples(n)

plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4.8))
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], '.', alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(data[:, 2], data[:, 3], '.', alpha=0.1)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

That code generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: how could I change this code to equate to 1 with 2 random neg and 2 pos?